# Magento : 2 How to solve a error of messageManager like “Recoverable Error: Object of class”?

Tags: magento2

When I have created a block to the show a custom success message on the checkout page. I have used

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('your' .$currencySymbol.$amount. ' amount' ));
```

But when I am running the code I  got this type of error: 
Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Framework\Message\Manager could not be converted to string in "my file path".

Please help me. How to solve my error?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Show how you get $currencySymbol and $amount?

Comment: $amount=500;  $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('your' .$amount.' amount' )); try this code if msg print correctly , the issue is your $currencySymbol.$amount values  not working properly

Comment: I get currecncy symbol using `$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();` and amount `$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getSubtotal();`.

Comment: $ccode = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$amount =$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getSubtotal();

echo $ccode;
echo $amount;
die;  //please check the values are proper working

Comment: @ShafeelSha all values are working properly. If I print only "hello" then show in cart page, but when I code `$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('hello' ));` then show error.

Comment: \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,     did you add this

Comment: Yes, I have already added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Block and you return the message in return then don't do that just set the message in the messageManager and return true. You just set the message don't return to the phtml file.

Like just leave it 
`$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('your' .$currencySymbol.$amount. ' amount' ));`

Not trying to set in return like this 
`return $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('your' .$currencySymbol.$amount. ' amount' ));`